# How to know the quadrant $\sec(-\pi/4)$ lies in?

Tags: trigonometry

It is in quadrant four and since the angle is negative it moves clockwise but how do you know it is in quadrant four? For instance, I know $11\pi/6$ is in quadrant four because I divide $11$ by $6$ and get $1.833333$ which is greater than $3\pi/2$,  but when I take $1$ divided by $4$ or $pi$ divided by $4$, I thought that would mean it is in the first quadrant.

Comment: The angle $-\pi/4$ is in the first$^*$ quadrant -- the first quadrant you encounter moving backwards, which is quadrant 4. (Also, note that $\sec(-\pi/4)$ is a number and doesn't really live in any quadrant)

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the *angle* $-\pi/4$ that belongs in the fourth quadrant, not its secant.

If you have a negative angle, just add $2\pi$ until you get a positive number (or $0$). In this case
$$
-\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi=\frac{7\pi}{4}
$$
and
$$
\frac{3\pi}{2}<\frac{7\pi}{4}<2\pi
$$